# Find the cumulative distribution function given a pdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A distribution X is described by the probability density function

$f(x) = \frac{x}{\alpha^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}}$, where $x\ge0.$

Find the cumulative distribution function.

---

What I have so far is $F(x) = 1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}}$ for $x\ge0$ using the integral
$\int^{x}_0\frac{t}{\alpha^2}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\alpha^2}}dt$ .

Is this all I need? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: But $x\ge0$ though so why should that be considered? Confused

Comment: Oops.  You're right.

Comment: They asked you to find the CDF, and you found it! You are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\alpha \neq 0$, your answer is correct.  (If $\alpha = 0$, the PDF is undefined, so there's not much to do there either.)

Comment: Does it change anything if the distribution is only defined when $\alpha^2>0$?

Comment: @Sonjov : Notice that for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha^2 > 0$ and $\alpha \neq 0$ are equivalent.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks.